# return not returning an accurate value in C

Tags: c, recursion, return-value

I had written this code which has the recursive function differ, when I run it, using the printf statements I notice that the code executes in the proper direction and I get the required value printed by the printf statement at the end of differ function but that value is not immediately returned instead the recursion goes again in the reverse direction and returns a wrong value. I have been struggling to debug it but I do not understand why it does not return immediately after it executes the last printf statement. Please help!!
To run enter:
5 3 1
0 3 8 5 12
1 3
as the input

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

long long int df;

long long max(long long int a,long long int b)
{
    long long int maxi;
    maxi = a>b ? a:b;
    return maxi;
}

long long min(long long int x,long long int y,long long int *a)
{
    long long int mini;
    mini = a[x]<a[y] ? (x+1):(y+1);
    return mini;
}

long long differ(long long int n1,long long int n2,long long int *a,long long int k,long long int n)
{
    long long int df,i;
    df=a[n1-1]-a[n2-1];
    df=abs(df);
    printf("%lld\n",df);

    if(df>k)
    {
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {   
            if(max(a[n1-1],a[n2-1])>a[i] && (max(a[n1-1],a[n2-1])-a[i])<=k)
            {
                printf("%lld %lld\n",a[i],a[min(n1-1,n2-1,a)-1]);
                differ(i+1,min(n1-1,n2-1,a),a,k,n);
return df; //Even this does not work
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%lld 90909\n",df);/*This does print a required value but changes again and returns a wrong value finally.*/
    return df;
}

int main()
{
    long long int n,k,p,f1,f2,d=0,i,j;
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    long long int a[n];
    scanf("%lld",&k);

    scanf("%lld",&p);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lld",&a[i]);
    }
    while(p-- > 0)
    {
        scanf("%lld",&f1);
        scanf("%lld",&f2);
        printf("%lld df\n",d);

        d = differ(f1,f2,a,k,n);

        printf("%lld diff",d);
        if(d<=k)
        {
            printf("Yes\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("No\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because in the recursive call you don't get the returned value?

Comment: yes, but I don't understand how to resolve it

Comment: It's hard to follow, but (1) the printf occurs after the recursive call and hence will appear "on exit" and will reflect the return order, and (2) your `differ` function doesn't appear to return any value to the prior invocation of itself, nor does it modify any of its parameters in a way that would be reflected back to the caller, so the recursive calls have no effect.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks a lot! I feel ur second point might be of use for me but, can u also mention how can I make it work properly,please

Comment: Use the returned value in the caller, I suppose.  I have no idea what your algorithm is trying to do, so I can't tell you precisely what to do with it.

Comment: Hint: Comments aren't only to make it easier for others to read your code.

Comment: My doubt is when the print statement which has 90909 in it printf the correct value, why doesn't the return statement return that value?

Comment: What is the desired output, provided input of `5 3 1 0 3 8 5 12 1 3`?

Comment: initially df should be 8 then reduces to 5 and then finally 3.So the output is supposed to be 3. But df becomes 3 but goes back to 8 and returns 8,don't know why!

Comment: "why doesn't the return statement return that value?" Return it to where??  You don't assign the returned value to anything.

Comment: `differ(i+1,min(n1-1,n2-1,a),a,k,n);` -- the result of that expression is dropped on the floor.  You might as well have skipped the call altogether.

Comment: @HotLicks I have used the returned value in main function as d. What do I do for the result of differ(i+1,min(n1-1,n2-1,a),a,k,n); not be dropped

Comment: You're not using it for the recursive call within `differ`.  So whatever is returned from that recursive call is ignored.  I have no idea what your algorithm is supposed to be doing, so I can't say what you should do with the returned value, but one presumes you should do *something* with it.

Comment: @HotLicks So do you say that I have to put a return statement to return the value difference after the recursive call. Please would you mention the changes I need to do. I did not get what the mistake is, for the returned value to be ignored.

Comment: You have to *assign* the *result* of the call to some variable, and then (appropriately) use that variable in your calculations.  Otherwise the recursive call might as well not take place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning the recursive function to df would solve the problem, that is

```
df=differ(i+1,min(n1-1,n2-1,a,k,n);
```

Hope it helps someone who is struggling with this small mistake during recursion.